# Multiple file upload constraint

Tags: symfony, assert

I'm followed the tutorial to manage the upload of multiple files http://growingcookies.com/easy-multiple-file-upload-in-symfony-using-the-collectiontype-field/

The system for uploading multiple files works fine.

However, I would like to add a constraint to allow only certain types of files and to set a maximum size.

For that, I add `@Assert\File`:

```
/**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "300k",
 *     mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf", "text/plain", "application/msword",
 *     "application/vnd.ms-excel", "image/jpeg", "image/x-citrix-jpeg", "image/png", "image/x-citrix-png", "image/x-png", "image/gif",
 *     "application/zip"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Liste des formats de fichiers acceptés : PDF, TXT, DOC, XLS, JPG, PNG, GIF"
 * )
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Maps_red\TicketingBundle\Entity\TicketDocument", mappedBy="ticket", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $documents;
```

By adding that, the code does not work anymore. I get the following error :

> Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a null variable.

This error appears on the Add Files page when I send the form. The line corresponding to the error is:

```
<div class="col col-xs-11" id="jsPreview{{ pos }}">{{ doc.vars.value.name }}</div>
```

The constraint violation message is : `"The file could not be found."`

Do you know where my error is ?

---

### Edit for @Denis Alimov:

I tried the answer of Denis Alimov with `@Assert\All` but it returns the same error.
I then tried to put the constraint in the BuildForm. Now, the .txt files pass without error, but all the other extensions always return me the same error

> Impossible to access an attribute ("name") on a null variable.

---

### Edit for @Jakumi:

### My twig :

```
{% extends '@Ticketing/base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ 'New Ticket'|trans({}, 'TicketingBundle') }}{% endblock %}
{% block header %}<h1>{{ 'New Ticket'|trans({}, 'TicketingBundle') }}</h1>{% endblock %}

{% block form_group_class -%}
    col-sm-8
{%- endblock form_group_class %}


{% block main %}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    {% form_theme form 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' _self %}

    <div class="box box-danger">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">{{ 'Create a new ticket'|trans({}, 'TicketingBundle') }}</h3>
        </div>

        {% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' _self %}

        {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'} }) }}
        <div class="box-body">

            <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

            <div id="filesProto" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.documents.vars.prototype)|e }}"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="ticket_form_documents">Pièce-jointe</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8" id="filesBox">
                    {% set pos = 0 %}
                    {% for doc in form.documents %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col col-xs-1" id="jsRemove{{ pos }}" style="">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeFile($(this));"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-xs-11" id="jsPreview{{ pos }}">{{ doc.vars.value.name }}</div>

                            <div style="display:none">
                                {{ form_widget(doc) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        {% set pos = pos + 1 %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->

        <div class="box-footer">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8">

                <button id="dropbutton" class="btn bg-ticketing btn-flat form-control" type="submit">
                    {{ 'Submit the ticket'|trans({}, 'TicketingBundle') }}
                </button>


            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-footer -->
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>

    <script>
        var fileCount = '{{ form.documents|length }}';
        var removeButton = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' onclick='removeFile($(this));'><i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i></button>";
        function removeFile(ob)
        {
            ob.parent().parent().remove();
        }
        function createAddFile(fileCount)
        {
            // grab the prototype template
            var newWidget = $("#filesProto").attr('data-prototype');
            // replace the "__name__" used in the id and name of the prototype
            newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, fileCount);
            newWidget = "<div style='display:none'>" + newWidget + "</div>";
            hideStuff = "";
            hideStuff += "<div class='col col-xs-1' id='jsRemove" + fileCount + "' style='display: none;'>";
            hideStuff += removeButton;
            hideStuff += "</div>";
            hideStuff += "<div class='col col-xs-11' id='jsPreview" + fileCount + "'>";
            hideStuff += "</div>";
            hideStuff += "<div class='col-sm-8'>";
            hideStuff += "<button type='button' id='jsBtnUpload" + fileCount + "' class='btn btn-default'>";
            hideStuff += "<i class='fa fa-plus'></i> {{ 'Pièce-jointe' | trans }}";
            hideStuff += "</button>";
            hideStuff += "</div>";
            $("#filesBox").append("<div class='form-group'>" + hideStuff + newWidget + "</div>");
            // On click => Simulate file behaviour
            $("#jsBtnUpload" + fileCount).on('click', function(e){
                $('#ticket_form_documents_' + fileCount + '_file').trigger('click');
            });
            // Once the file is added
            $('#ticket_form_documents_' + fileCount + '_file').on('change', function() {
                // Show its name
                fileName = $(this).prop('files')[0].name;
                $("#jsPreview" + fileCount).append(fileName);
                // Hide the add file button
                $("#jsBtnUpload" + fileCount).hide();
                // Show the remove file button
                $("#jsRemove" + fileCount).show();
                // Create another instance of add file button and company
                createAddFile(parseInt(fileCount)+1);
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            createAddFile(fileCount);
            fileCount++;
        });
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

---

### Edit :

With {{ doc.vars.value.name ?? '' }} I do not have the error anymore !!

However, the file deletion buttons remain displayed:

```
<div class="col col-xs-1" id="jsRemove1" style="">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeFile($(this));"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

How to make these buttons disappear when a file type is not good?

Comment: I assume, that since `$documents` is a collection and not a (single!) file, that it will fail cause of that. Have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html and probably define an initial value for `$documents` (like `[]`). but it also may be unrelated.

Comment: @Jakumi Thank for your help but I just tried, I still have the same problem :(

Comment: As Jakumi says Your $documents field is no longer a File but a Collection. You could initiate it as a new Arraycollection() in your class constructor.

Comment: It's already done. I manage to upload several files. That's when I add the constraint that it does not work anymore

Comment: I believe, that the constraint is (now) actually working fine, but your `jsPreview` stuff is NOT. Meaning: when your form has errors, it will try to show stuff about your last request, and tries to refill your form with that data. And there's probably some problem with that code ... so I guess you should also show your twig code where the posted `doc.vars.value.name` is located. it's probably enough to append `?? ''` to `doc.vars.value.name`.

Comment: Indeed, I will lean on this side. I edited my post with my twig code

Comment: @Jakumi I have no more error with `{{ doc.vars.value.name ?? '' }}` however, the files are still existing so I have the btn-danger buttons to delete those files that still appear. How to delete existing files when there is an error or how to remove these buttons? thx

Comment: I think, that there is an *entry* of the file, but the file isn't actually there (thus `null`).  I don't actually know, how to handle failed file uploads for multiple file forms. I would have assumed, that the form component would handle that on its own ... or that the tutorial would actually contain that information. Essentially the FileType shows, as an example, that you use a different field for the stored files, as far as I can tell. But I haven't gone through "your" linked tutorial though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned use [All constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html) like this

```
 /**
 * @Assert\All({
 *     @Assert\File(
 *         maxSize = "300k",
 *         mimeTypes = {"application/pdf", "application/x-pdf", "text/plain", "application/msword", "application/vnd.ms-excel", "image/jpeg", "image/x-citrix-jpeg", "image/png", "image/x-citrix-png", "image/x-png", "image/gif","application/zip"},
 *         mimeTypesMessage = "Liste des formats de fichiers acceptés : PDF, TXT, DOC, XLS, JPG, PNG, GIF"
 *     )
 * })
 */
 private $documents;
```

Also you can add constraints to your DocumentType in the buildForm method

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried the `@Assert\All` but it returns the same error. I also tried to add the constraints in the buildForm and only the .txt files works. I edited my first post